# How do I make Alt-Tab show a visible window that has no taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, alt-tab

In Windows 7, does Alt+Tab now only display windows that have a taskbar button? Windows without a taskbar button are not showing up in the Alt+Tab list.

This is somewhat annoying to say the least. Visible dialogs without a taskbar button obviously cannot be selected via the taskbar, and they can't be selected via Alt+Tab either?

The application in question is a legacy (pre-Vista) app that creates a simple window without a taskbar button. Windows XP displays it in the task switcher. Windows 7 does not.

Comment: This looks like something [Old New Thing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/08/426720.aspx) [could answer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/01/17/1483974.aspx)... but for the first time I can't find a really relevant post. :-C

Comment: @grawity: Your googling skillz have failed you :) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/10/08/5351207.aspx

Comment: This would be bad if _all_ invisible windows were added to Alt-Tab

Comment: If you know how, it would be trivial to write an app that used `FindWindow` and `PostMessage` to send this window the `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` message. This forces the window onto the taskbar.

Answer (score 3):

Windows allows any program to NOT include itself in the taskbar and thus not include itself in the Alt Tab list.

And there is no public API to change the Task Switcher (God help us if third party programs were allowed to!).

So essentially the problem boils down to, "*Program A* does not show up in the Task Switcher. How do I make *Program A* show up in the Task Switcher?"

Comment: *> And there is no public API to change the Task Switcher (God help us if third party programs were allowed to!).* Do you means specifically in Windows 7? XP certainly had the option, both [officially](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-xp) and [third-party](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,1912345,00.asp), and they work in Windows 7.

Comment: @Synetechinc.:  I have no idea how the Alt-Tab power toy worked. But from I can tell, the only way to replace the Task Switcher is to install a global hook and intercept the keyboard call. In otherwords, it's not an API. There are Win32 calls to reorder the windows and such . . .